# Views Bulk Operations with Field Collection Item tokens

Tags: views

I am trying to modify the values of one field in all instances of a field collection type. 
I have a view listing all field collection items, that I want and an operation field with modify entity. Setting value in the field works fine, but I can't use any tokens from the current item, only site tokens are available.

Can this be done with VBO? Are there any other easy ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view of nodes, rather than field collections, then add the collection as a **Relationship**.

[image]

Your node tokens should now be available for application to the field collection fields.

Comment: I may have misread your question. Did you want tokens from the node, or from the field collection fields?

Comment: I want tokens from the field collection. Still this might work if there is access to the field collection item fields in the node tokens. I will have to test

Comment: In my test install the field collection fields do not provide tokens via node tokens, just a token representing the collection itself. Sorry

Comment: I did find this module while reseraching: https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tokens

Comment: This might work, I was also thinking of trying Advanced entity tokens https://www.drupal.org/project/aet

Comment: field_collection_tokens is only just out of sandbox, so take precautions